How to iterate over a second level of multifield on AEM
I'm working with Adobe Experience Manager. What I need to build is a component, where the user can create certain amount of containers, and inside of each container, they can create any amount of information cards. On my .content.xml document for the _cq_dialog folder I have:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          jcr:title="Tabs and Content"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
          extraClientlibs="[project.base]">
    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <tabs jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/tabs">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <properties jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:title="Tabs" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns" margin="{Boolean}true">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <card
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                fieldlabel="General"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                                composite="{Boolean}true">
                                    <field jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/fieldset" name="./tabsGroup">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <titleTab jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield" fieldLabel="Titulo de la tab" name="./titleTab"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </field>
                                </card>
                            </items>
                        </column>
                        </items>
                    </properties>
                    <cardBlock jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:title="Content" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns" margin="{Boolean}true">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <column
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <cardBody
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            fieldlabel="Contenedor de cards"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                                            composite="{Boolean}true">
                                        <field jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/fieldset" name="./contentGroup">
                                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                <titleBlock jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield" fieldLabel="Titulo del bloque" name="./titleBlock"/>
                                                <cardData
                                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                        fieldlabel="Contenedor de cards"
                                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                                                        composite="{Boolean}true">
                                                    <field jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/fieldset" name="./contentData">
                                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                            <image
                                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathfield"
                                                                    fieldLabel="Image URL"
                                                                    rootPath="/content/dam/project"
                                                                    name="./image">
                                                            </image>
                                                            <altImage
                                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                                    fieldLabel="Alt image"
                                                                    name="./altImage"/>
                                                            <clientName
                                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                                    fieldLabel="Mes"
                                                                    name="./clientName"/>
                                                        </items>
                                                    </field>
                                                </cardData>
                                            </items>
                                        </field>
                                    </cardBody>
                                </items>
                            </column>
                        </items>
                    </cardBlock>
                </items>
            </tabs>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>

As you can see, to reach what i need, I have to add a multifield inside another multifield. My problems is that I can't reach the information inside the second multifield. My java model looks like:
package com.project.core.models;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.DefaultInjectionStrategy;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.ChildResource;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Model(adaptables = Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class TabsAndContentModel {

    @ChildResource
    private List<Resource> tabsGroup;

    @ChildResource
    private  List<Resource> contentGroup;

    public List<Resource> getTabsGroup() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(tabsGroup);
    }

    public List <Resource> getContentGroup() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(contentGroup);
    }

}


With tabsGroup I'm getting the title of the container, and with contentGroup I'm triying to get the card information. I tried iterating like this, but didn't work:
<sly data-sly-use.model="com.project.core.models.TabsAndContentModel">

    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="tabs-one" >
                <ol role="tablist" 
                    aria-multiselectable="false">
                    <sly data-sly-list.b="${model.tabsGroup}">
                        <li role="tab" id="tab1"                            
                            tabindex="0" data-tab-index="0">${b.titleTab}</li>
                    </sly>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <sly data-sly-list.cardData="${model.contentGroup}">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>
                                        ${cardData.titleBlock}</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <select>
                                                <option value="all">All</option>
                                                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <sly data-sly-list.cardData="${model.contentGroup}">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="${cardData.image}" alt="${cardData.altImage}">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h6>${cardData.name}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </sly>
            </sly>
        </div>
    </div>

</sly>

Can anyone help me or guide me, please? I just need a way to iterate over contentGroup to obtain the information an show it on front end.
Thanks in advance

What exactly does not work? Can you provide a screenshot from node view from CRX?

I've tried serveral ways and I think you have to create an extra subcomponent or an extra model class.

There are multiple ways achieve your use-case.
Assuming your node structure looks like -
-- tabsGroup
      - item0
      - item1
      - item2
-- contentGroup
      - item0 [titleBlock = "something"]
          - contentData
              - item0 [image, altImage, clientName]
              - item1 [image, altImage, clientName]
              - item2 [image, altImage, clientName]
      - item1 [titleBlock = "something2"]
          - contentData
              - item0 [image, altImage, clientName]
              - item1 [image, altImage, clientName]
              - item2 [image, altImage, clientName]              
      - item2 [titleBlock = "something3"]
          - contentData
              - item0 [image, altImage, clientName]
              - item1 [image, altImage, clientName]
              - item2 [image, altImage, clientName]

The simplest one will be -

create 2 SlingModel one for the ContentGroup and one for ContentData
add PostConstruct to your TabsAndContentModel, loop through contentGroup list you have from @ChildResource and for each resource adapt it to ContentGroup.class
In ContentGroup sling model use @ChildResource contentData and same way implement PostConstruct looping through contentData adapting each to ContentData.class
Provide relevant getters for the elements
This way you will be able to access the nested multifield information

On side note - Your dialog with two multifields with one being nested multifield makes authoring complicated and as our entries in multifield increases, it will cause load issues with component dialog for editing.
If possible redesign this experience either using Content Fragments or Composable Authoring using (Tabs component [tabs group] with nested containers [Content Group] and teaser/custom-component for content data) or some variation of it matching your functional requirements.
